# Using getBounds on geoJSON feature

Tags: leaflet, geojson

I've tried `map.fitBounds(geojsonFeature.getBounds());` and I get this error:

> geojsonFeature.getBounds() is not a function.

Here is the code: http://jsfiddle.net/0aqxktov/

What is going wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your variable `geojsonFeature` is just an object, there is no method named `getBounds()` there, as you can easily check.

Instead of that, give your geoJSON layer a name...

```
var feature = L.geoJson(geojsonFeature).addTo(map);
```

And use that to call `getBounds()`:

```
map.fitBounds(feature.getBounds());
```

Here is the updated JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qofrgm2k/

Comment: "Running fiddle"
"<a class='gotoLine' href='#50:1'>50:1</a> Uncaught ReferenceError: L is not defined"